# multiple autofilters for the same EPPlus worksheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus, autofilter

Im creating an xlsx-file using EPPlus and want to have autofilters for all headers. I set the autofilters like this:

```
worksheet.Cells["A3:G" + (3 + data.Count).ToString()].AutoFilter = true;
```

This works smooth for just one table of content. However, I have two separate tables in the same worksheet, and when trying to set autofilters for the second one, the autofilters for the first one disappears.

Any known workarounds for this, or other suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very good question!

A traditional limitation of AutoFilter is that it can be applied only once on a worksheet.

Starting with Excel 2007 you can create several **Tables** on a worksheet...........each with filtering capabilities.

See [Pieterse's Article](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/Excel2007tables.asp)

Comment: As suspected. Thanks, I'll give tables a try.

Comment: Did tables allow you to have two sets of autofilters active in the same sheet?